# Min and Max date from Slicer in Power Bi disregarding visual level filters

Tags: powerbi

Good day,

I am trying to get the min and max date of a `date slicer` in `Power Bi` as a static variable, disregarding the rest of the visual filters. For some reason even though I included the `ALL` statement in my measure to exclude the one filter associated -which is inventory Id, when I select an Inventory Item (which is in the same table as the date), the date min/max changes.

```
MinDateSelected = CALCULATE(
        Min('Total Inventory Received'[Date] ),
        ALLSELECTED( 'Total Inventory Received'[Date] ),all('Total Inventory Received'[InventoryID])
    )
```

I searched many documentations, but cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: use a different table for your slicer . Insted of 'Total Inventory Received' use 'Calendar'[Date]

Comment: @msta42a -thank you, issue is, I need the date to interact with my visuals, but need the static date as well. So if I use the calendar date as the date slicer, and only make a one way join, my other visuals don't update